# ng2-pdf-viewer problem with Angular >=12 version

Tags: angular, angular13, angular15, pdfjs-dist, ng2-pdf-viewer

**Error**

1. If 'pdf-viewer' is an Angular component and it has 'src' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'pdf-viewer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

My module where I'm importing this

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    
    import { BillingClaimsRoutingModule } from './billing-claims-routing.module';
    import { BillingClaimsComponent } from './billing-claims.component';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { ApplicationServiceService } from '../service/application-service.service';
    import { ClaimService } from '../service/claim.service';
    import { DownLoadService } from '../service/download.service';
    import { PipesModule } from '../pipe/pipe-module';
    import { AttachFileModule } from '../shared/attach-file/attach-file.module';
    import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
    
    import {PdfViewerModule} from "ng2-pdf-viewer";
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [BillingClaimsComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BillingClaimsRoutingModule,
        FormsModule,
        PipesModule,
        AttachFileModule,
        PdfViewerModule
      ],
      providers: [ApplicationServiceService, ClaimService, DownLoadService, DatePipe],
      exports: [BillingClaimsComponent]
    })
    export class BillingClaimsModule { }
```

My template where I'm using it

> pacakge.json
>
> ```
>         private": true,
>       "dependencies": {
>         "@angular/animations": "15.2.0",
>         "@angular/common": "15.2.0",
>         "@angular/compiler": "15.2.0",
>         "@angular/core": "15.2.0",
>         "@angular/forms": "15.2.0",
>         "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.0",
>         "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.0",
>         "@angular/router": "15.2.0",
>         "ng-recaptcha": "^11.0.0",
>         "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^10.0.0",
>         "pdfjs-dist": "^4.0.379",
>         "ngx-csv": "^0.3.2",
>         "rxjs": "7.5.0",
>         "tslib": "2.3.0",
>         "zone.js": "0.11.4"
>       },
>       "devDependencies": {
>         "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.0",
>         "@angular/cli": "15.2.0",
>         "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.2.0",
>         "@types/jasmine": "4.0.0",
>         "jasmine-core": "4.1.0",
>         "karma": "^6.4.1",
>         "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
>         "karma-coverage": "2.2.0",
>         "karma-jasmine": "5.0.0",
>         "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.7.0",
>         "typescript": "4.8.4"
>       }
> ```

I'm taking a exmaple of this same package and with same code from this link

```
    `https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-pdf-viewer?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts`
```

app.module.ts

```
{
    path: 'billing-claims/:uuid',
    loadChildren: () => import("./claims/claims.module").then(m => m.ClaimsModule),
  },
```

claims.module.ts

```
import { ClaimsRoutingModule } from './claims-routing.module';
import { BillingClaimsModule } from '../billing-claims/billing- 
claims.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ClaimsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ClaimsRoutingModule,
    BillingClaimsModule
  ]
})
export class ClaimsModule
```

claims.component.html :

```
<app-billing-claims></app-billing-claims>
```

Comment: please share the component name where this issues is occouring, also the module on which you are importing the component!

Comment: Please post the code as  a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: basically the component is lazy loaded and in that I'm importing this ng2-pdf-viewer module , wait I'm sharing

Comment: @NarenMurali component name is BillingComponent

Comment: @AyushSrivastava please share the module that has the `BillingComponent` in its declarations array!

Answer (score 0):

Since we are using the declaration component `app-billing-claims` of `BillingClaimsModule` inside the `ClaimsModule`.

Only the exports array of `BillingClaimsModule` is visible to the `ClaimsModule`, so that means it has access to only `BillingClaimsComponent`

Note: the imports (`BillingClaimsModule`) are not visible to `ClaimsModule`

To fix this. Kindly add the module for pdf viewer on the `BillingClaimsModule` exports array!

```
...
@NgModule({
      declarations: [BillingClaimsComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BillingClaimsRoutingModule,
        FormsModule,
        PipesModule,
        AttachFileModule,
        PdfViewerModule
      ],
      providers: [ApplicationServiceService, ClaimService, DownLoadService, DatePipe],
      exports: [BillingClaimsComponent, PdfViewerModule] // <- changed here!
    })
    export class BillingClaimsModule { }
```

---

As per the details provided, the problem lies on `BillingComponent` but the module containing the component is not provided.

So follow these steps to solve your issue.

- Search your project as to where the component with the problem, has been added to the `declarations` array of which module!
- Then validate that module and ensure you are having `PdfViewerModule` in the imports array of that module

Note: When it comes to lazy loaded modules, the imports need to be imported separately and it will not inherit the imports from the parent/root module!

Comment: I have verified , all imports are correct

Comment: @AyushSrivastava But you never shared the import of `BillingComponent` please check the question!

Comment: Re check once Sir , I have re edit the code , ClaimsModule has the import of BillingModule and that ClaimsModule is lazy loaded from AppModule as I have shared

Comment: claims.component.html : code  ===== > <app-billing-claims></app-billing-claims> , in template its only this single line there

Comment: Selector of BillingsModule === > @Component({
  selector: 'app-billing-claims',
  templateUrl: './billing-claims.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./billing-claims.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

Comment: it was CUSTOM_SCHEMA_ISSUE ==> import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';   .....   exports: [BillingClaimsComponent],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ], .....and also version of  "pdfjs-dist": "3.1.81",  worked for me !

Comment: @AyushSrivastava did you try my solution, its not recommended to do `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` all angular html errors will be disabled, which is not good and should not be done!